Why does my laptop have high power consumption in sleep mode (10-80 watts)?
So I recently bought Asus ROG Strix G16 (2024) laptop but I noticed a high power consumption in sleep mode (10-80 watts).
It jumps periodically from 10 to 80 watts but it should only power RAM and some other stuff, but 20+ watts is too much...
Here is a video link.

What could be the problem or is it how Asus laptops or any others actually work in sleep mode?
Power modes:
powercfg -a

The following sleep states are available on this system:

Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Connected
Hibernate
Fast Startup
The following sleep states are not available on this system:

Standby (S1)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.
This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

Standby (S2)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.
This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

Standby (S3)
This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.
Hybrid Sleep

Standby (S3) is not available.
The hypervisor does not support this standby state.


Is it charging? At first glance that seems about normal for a laptop that is charging. (Is it set to default "charge to 100%" mode?)

@grawity_u1686 no, it's not charging, the laptop would have a red LED (second LED) below display, and I usually use this laptop only with AC power. P.s. It was like this from the beginning - about a weak, and laptop was always charged

@John I guess it's something related to "modern standby (S0 sleep)" which is not really good but laptop doesn't support others, only this one. Which mode do you have on your laptop? can be checked with powercfg /a command (Windows)

@John which laptop do you have? Mb this issue is more related to gaming laptops like in my case

@John I guess you have S3 mode active then

@John, "it should not use power in true sleep state." That is wrong. sleep uses little power, but it keeps the CPU running, and RAM refreshed and powered, so that it can wake almost instantly. Hibernation serializes RAM to the drive, and use no power (however, some PC's do bleed power in hibernation for various reasons). To prove the point, remove AC & battery from a PC in hibernation, wait, reapply power, and it will un-hibernate. Do that in sleep, and it must reboot completely.

@John found a solution to change S0 standby mode to S3, now I have the same power consumption. So your laptop definitely has S3 mode by default. Mb you have an older Windows version or laptop doesn't support modern Standby


It's not only powering the ram, cpu is still doing stuff. Windows has
this thing called modern standby also known as S0 sleep. All windows
laptops have it and when you put the laptop in sleep, it enters a "low
power stage". Depending on being connected to the charger or not, it
will go in S0 network connected or S0 network disconnected. With
network connected it can download updates and stuff, receive VoIP
calls etc. Also modern standby S0 is what makes that instant wakeup
from sleep possible. Your laptop is probably doing something in the
background when you checked like getting updates.
The old sleep state that has only ram active is called S3 sleep. Most
laptops don't even support it in their firmware anymore (Asus is one
of the few that still does) but you need to do some work in windows if
you want it instead of S0.

from the comment https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUSROG/comments/1cpgtrd/comment/l3lhdhl/
And the solution I have tried to disable S0 mode:
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0 (in Terminal with admin rights of course)
I rebooted the laptop (mandatory to make changes) and it seems changed the mode to S3:

The following sleep states are available on this system:

Standby (S3)

Hibernate

Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:

Standby (S1)

The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S2)

The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)

The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Hybrid Sleep

The hypervisor does not support this standby state.


p.s. if for someone it won't work, use reg delete "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power" /v PlatformAoAcOverride /f to undo changes
Sleep mode options didn't disappear after this as it was happening for some other laptop owners (I believe their firmware didn't support S3)
And it actually works fine, so RAM, USB hub with separated power supply connected, and a external monitor in idle mode only use 0.5 W now:

Update:
Though it works but only if I put the laptop to sleep manually using "Right click on Windows/Shut down or sign out/Sleep", in all other cases like automatic Windows timeout sleep, power button on the laptop or "ALT+F4 / Sleep"  make the laptop sleep and instantly wakes it up for some reason. Why does it work differently? Is there any solution?
Update 2 SOLVED:
I found the reason why laptop automatically wakes up right after it goes to the sleep mode (in cases like automatic Windows timeout sleep, power button on the laptop or "ALT+F4 / Sleep") - external usb keyboard was causing it, though external usb mouse works fine and doesn't cause this issue, so I just disabled the option in power management of the external keyboard to wake the laptop, but I can still use a mouse or built-in laptop keyboard anyway to wake it up. So now it works in all cases! So weird... when I previously "Right click on Windows/Shut down or sign out/Sleep" it wasn't the issue for automatic awakening :)

